# line d3.js graph shifting wrongly (to right)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Because I am having an issue with my own code, I am studying below link:

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

I think I get below

```
// push a new data point onto the back
data.push(random());

// redraw the line, and then slide it to the left
path
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");

// pop the old data point off the front
data.shift();
```

But the part that doesn't work for me and I don't understand is

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");
```

My code's x is like below:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([-5, width])
```

domain is not known at this time and later domain is defined as

```
x.domain(d3.extent(callbackData, function(d){return d.reg_date;}));
```

I try to use x(-1) but entire graph(except axis) disappears when I call for update so I use something like below and initially, it seems to work.(graph shifts to the left). But as more data comes in(btw, my data comes in and updates the data properly(shift off the front data and push latest into the back) graph starts to shifting towards the right. I can see graph start taking points from the front(which is correct) but problem is, graph is starting to shift to right(instead of left).
Really beating my head w/ this issue so hopefully someone can kindly advise.

```
        path
          .attr("d",line)
           .attr('transform', null)
          .transition()
           .duration(300)
           .ease('linear')
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + -2  + ")");
```

Comment: the x(-1) is used to move the graph to the left. So the push adds one to the right and the shift removes the first element. If you could mock up a JSFiddle we could give you a hand

Comment: Thank you. I am gonna sleep few hours now nd really work that mock up.  Have been looking at this all night with little bit of progress but really stuck with this but i need to sleep few hours.

Comment: Ok. Just a question, are you using the last bit of code you posted ? As it won't work properly if you are. The translate has to pass through the scales (x/y)  so it scales properly on the graph. So the (-2) should be x(-2)

Comment: Right.  But the thing is when i do that graph dissapears and i am not sure how to troubleshoot that.  When i do just -2 at least it appears to work for one sample

Comment: can you select it in the DOM and see where it moves to ?

Comment: Hmmm not exactly sure what you mean but right now my eyes are almost shutting down from looking at this thing all night.  I will get the mock up ready first thing when i wake up in few hours.  Thank you so much

Comment: Finally here is the jsfiddle.. Please take a look. thank you       https://jsfiddle.net/askingquestionsagain/j2eovk9k/4/

Comment: It's because your x scale is working with dates

Comment: okay, x scale is working with dates.. is there no way to shift that to left?

Comment: also in dev console, when I want to take a look at what inside of callbackData, it says it is not defined for some reason(even though clearly data was in there as it drew the initial graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick implementation : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/j2eovk9k/8/

I have added this to work out distance between the x ticks :

```
var testtickArr = y.ticks(10);
var testtickDistance = y(testtickArr[testtickArr.length - 2]) - y(testtickArr[testtickArr.length - 1]);
```

Then used this as the distance to move the path :

```
path
.attr("d", line) 
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.ease('linear')
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  console.log(d)
  return "translate(" + (pathTrans) + ")";
})
```

Also, update the translation value :

```
  pathTrans -= testtickDistance;
```

The way you're updating your data can be improved. But this should help you with the transition. This is still not working ok at all as the distances between your points are not equal. For yours to work like the example you need equal distances between each points so it transitions to the left smoothly.

Comment: def moving to the left now.. just trying to figure out why new data is not being pushed into the callbackData array.

Comment: So I fixed to callbackData.push(callbackData1); on pushing the data into callbackData so now it gets updated but it looks like once initial graph is pushed out to the left, I am left with no more data being graphed(even though callbackData has 20 objects).

Comment: Also, I really don't understand why one needs to use y to figure out the distance between the x ticks. Can you please elaborate on that ? (I played w/ changing them to x.ticks and x() but it doesn't work as I thought it should be)

Comment: I think you had the same for updating.  So this is what I am looking at which is possibly how you left it in the first place.    But I am looking for graph to continue to get updated.. but after initial graphs are pushed to the left, it shows nothing.   https://jsfiddle.net/askingquestionsagain/j2eovk9k/10/

Comment: My bad, you are suppose to use x not y. and reverse the working out so its like this : var testtickDistance = x(testtickArr[testtickArr.length - 1]) - x(testtickArr[testtickArr.length - 2]);

Comment: I updated that but looks like still ...    https://jsfiddle.net/askingquestionsagain/j2eovk9k/13/

Comment: Yeah  i know. I have created this : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/j2eovk9k/15/ Read through the code. The transition doesn't work well, so i commented it out, but the data add/remove does. You need to update your axis aswel las the data in your update function

Comment: thank you. I think I have bothered you enough. this is great place for me to start. I will take a look. I really really appreciate you.. thank you

Comment: Sorry i havent had time to help you properly. This one may help you https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/hsrL5tdk/

Comment: You did MORE than I could ever imagine getting help here. thank you very much and I am going to really dig into this. thank you for your last example as well. thank you!

Comment: btw, one last problem that I am working on right now. I need the y axis to show the ticks with value and it says it's there but I do not see it.

Comment: Just shift the whole thing to the right, probably outside the size of the graph

Comment: Yes, when I shift the yAxis to translate about 40 on x coordinate, I do see it (but now it's inside of moving graph).. I need to somehow move the whole thing as you put it.. looking into it.

Comment: so now that I am good w/ that, now I have to deal w/ dynamic y axis which has huge range which is not working out well. I will create another post on separate page for this..thank you